# Having my arrays as one object and printing in a list

Tags: javascript, arrays

At the moment when I run my code it prints dog 1 for the name and then dog 2 for the number of toys, it also does this with the no. of toys, I need to have it printing so it is "Dog 1: (name)" and on the right of that the "No. of toys (number)". It should be going down in a list like that but I cant figure out how to make that happen. How can I fix this?

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("task").innerHTML = "Task 8";
  var arr = [];
  var vName = "";
  var vToys = "";
  vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
  vToys = parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)"));
  while (vName.length > 0) {
    arr.push(vName);
    arr.push(vToys);
    vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)");
    vToys = parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)"));
  }
  var name = function name(dogs) {
    return dogs.map(function(dogName, index) {
      return "Dog " + (index + 1) + ": " + dogName;
    });
  };
  var Tname = function Tname(toys) {
    return toys.map(function(toyNum) {
      return "No. of toys: " + toyNum;
    });
  };
  arr.forEach(function(entry) {
    var vOutput = "Dog names and No. of toys: <br/>" + name(arr).join("<br/>") + Tname(arr).join("<br/>");
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = vOutput;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the output in a single loop

```js
function start() {
  document.getElementById("task").innerHTML = "Task 8";
  var arr = [];
  var vName = "";
  var vToys = "";

  do {
    vName = prompt("Enter dog name (leave blank to stop)").trim();
    vToys = vName && parseInt(prompt("Enter dogs toys (leave blank to stop)").trim());
    if (vName && vToys) {
      arr.push({
        name: vName,
        nToys: vToys
      });
    }
  } while (vName && vToys)
  var vOutput = "Dog names and No. of toys: <br/>" + arr.map((dog, idx) => {
    return 'Dog: ' + dog.name + ', No of toys: ' + dog.nToys
  }).join('<br />');
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = vOutput;
}

start();
```

```html
<div id="task"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, one more thing how do I go about sorting the array so I can have dog name in alphabetically or toy number in ascending sequence